# Why mysql Fails to describe the table?

Tags: mysql

---

I have tried the following mysql command to describe the table but i gated with an error.let me know to clear this error.

```
mysql> desc bhappy;
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_14bb_0.MYI' (Errcode: 30)
```

Comment: Do you have rights to read the database ?

Comment: How to check permission for database(i tried show grants;).Is it right command to check.@ Rishabk Kumar

Comment: `perror 30` prints **Read-only file system**. Did you start MySQL Server as administrator? Is your OS or you MySQL Server installation corrupt?